How do you say "I sent two letters" in Latin?
In a known fragment of one of Cicero's letters to his son Marcus, it reads:
Cicero per epistulam culpat filium, dicens male eum dixisse ‘direxi litteras duas,’ cum ‘litterae,’ quotiens epistulam significant, numeri tantum pluralis sint. --Serv. Aen. 8, 168 ("Cicero answers his son in a letter, saying he should not have written direxi litteras duas [‘I sent two letters’], since litterae meaning ‘a letter’ can only be used in the plural.)
If that is the case, then how should a person write "I sent two letters" using the word litterae, or is that simply not possible and epistulae must be used instead? I notice that Plautus always writes epistulas duas, never litteras duas. So, perhaps this is the case, and litterae can only mean a single letter.

Does this answer your question? How do I specify how many "litterae" or "castra" there are?
